# Trouble initializing TurndownService for HTML to Markdown conversion in React component

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript, markdown

I'm encountering an issue when attempting to initialize TurndownService within a React component for converting HTML to Markdown. Here's a snippet of the code related to the problem:

```
import TurndownService  from 'turndown';

const NewTextGenForm = () => {
...
const handlePostButtonClick = () => {
  // Convert html to markdown
const turndownService = new TurndownService(); // <-- Error occurs here
const convertedMarkdown = turndownService.turndown(html);
}
...
```

The error message I'm getting is:

ERROR in src/components/forms/NewTextGenForm.tsx:279:33
TS2351: This expression is not constructable.
Type 'String' has no construct signatures.
277 |
278 |     // Convert html to markdown

> 279 |     const turndownService = new TurndownService();
> |                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> 280 |     const convertedMarkdown = turndownService.turndown(html);
> 281 |
> 282 |

I've imported TurndownService in my React component and attempted to create an instance of it to convert HTML to Markdown. However, it seems like there's an issue with this initialization.

Could someone shed light on what might be causing this error and how I can correctly initialize TurndownService for HTML to Markdown conversion within a React component?

Thank you in advance!